# Simulink thermal model initial temperature value

Tags: simulink

I was working on an example of simulink's thermal model [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/thermal-model-of-a-house.html), where I converted it into an AC and shared my steps in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352214/simulink-home-thermal-system-as-an-ac).

As I was working on it, I noticed that no matter how much I vary my setpoint temperature or my combfort levels, the output always starts from around 85 F and drops as shown in the figure below.

[image]

I think this could be an initial value issue but I checked all the initial values in the initialization .m file and changed them to suit my AC (Tin_init=26, T_heater=15 for AC).
The equations behind the model are shown in the official documentation of the [model](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/thermal-model-of-a-house.html), but there was no mention of anything that would explain the plot always starting from 85. Any idea what could cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The model is set-up with a `Model Workspace`, which means that when the model is being initialized it looks there first, before looking in the `Base Workspace`.  As per the picture below, the Model Workspace has a value for `TinIC`, which means this value is used, not any value that you may have in the Base Workspace.  To reinitialize the workspace you need to press that button indicated in the image below.

In your case you most likely want to remove the Model Workspace, and just have the model parameters picked up from the Base Workspace.  That way you can make changes and have them reflected in the simulation.

[image]

Comment: Yes I am aware of the initialization file,and I re_initialized the file with my new set values. Ideally; the plot should start from the initial indoor tempratue (regardless of its value). I only noticed this response when I leave T_heater =50 (temp of air comming out of the unit) ,which doesnt make sense for an AC. If I change it to another value, it get locked at that certain starting point as shown above. If I leave T_heater as 50 will this still be a valid AC?

Comment: What does "I re_initialized the file" mean?  (It could just mean you run it from the command line).  You haven't specifically addressed the issue I raised.  You must manually press the "Reinitialize from Source" any time you update the initialization file.  Are you doing that?